# npm doesn't work ubuntu16.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I installed nodejs and npm as is written [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment) but after having installed both of them, npm doesn't work. Always that I try to run any command like `npm -v`, `npm version`, `npm install express`, etc. It just print this:

```
Usage: npm <command>
where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit,
    explore, get, help, help-search, i, init, install,
    install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls,
    outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, profile, prune,
    publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run, run-script,
    s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t,
    team, test, token, tst, un, uninstall, unpublish, unstar,
    up, update, v, version, view, whoami

npm <command> -h     quick help on <command>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/user/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@5.6.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
```

It's as if the command was registered in the man but doesn't work  properly. I'm pretty new on this. I  don't get what is wrong with it.

The error is the same as if the sintax of the command were wrong. The print  is the same even if I run `npm any-string-here`.

I already tried to purge nodejs and erase all node_modules and libraries to make a clean install of nodejs and npm but the problem remains. What could be the wrong?

Note: Nodejs works fine. I can run `nodejs file.js` without problem. It's just npm who is not recognize.

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: Hi, I run it from ubuntu terminal but I also tried 'nodejs npm' but its the same print out.

Comment: How did you installed it? How is your path (run `echo $PATH`)

Comment: `bash: /home/user/bin:/home/jpp/.local/bin:/user/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. npm is in /usr/local/bin with nodejs

Comment: and how did you installed it?